# Adding Images to InfoBox in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to add an image to my custom infobox (please note this isn't an infoWindow). The script runs fine and loads properly until I add the 'img src' line to the HTML contents of the infoBox. From this point, nothing loads. I've been trying to figure it out and have found nothing online, everything I've found pertains to infoWindows.

Code Snippet:

```
 var marker_C = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         draggable: true,
         position: myCenter,
         visible: true
        });

        var boxText = document.createElement("div");
        boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: #f5c82f; padding: 5px;"; 
        boxText.innerHTML = "<strong>Taylor's House</strong>, Tallanasty<br><img border="0" src="/images/bar.jpg" alt="BAR" width="304" height="228"><br>The text for whats going on here<br>My Address Here";

        var myOptions = {
                 content: boxText,
                disableAutoPan: false,
                maxWidth: 0,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-180, 0),//X axis should be half the size of box width
                zIndex: null,
                boxStyle: { 
                  background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
                  opacity: 0.85,
                  width: "360px"
                 },
                closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
                closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
                isHidden: false,
                pane: "floatPane",
                enableEventPropagation: false
        };

        var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        ib.open(map, marker);
```

if I set 'boxText.innerHTML' equal to: `"<strong>Taylor's House</strong>, Tallanasty<br><br>The text for whats going on here<br>My Address Here";`
without the image, everything loads fine.

Hoping someone who's experienced this can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the double qoutes in your `innerHTML` string:

```
boxText.innerHTML = "<strong>Taylor's House</strong>, Tallanasty<br><img border=\"0\" src=\"/images/bar.jpg\" alt=\"BAR\" width=\"304\" height=\"228\"><br>The text for whats going on here<br>My Address Here";
```

Otherwise you get an error.

Comment: Thank you :) this is now loading! However, the image itself isn't loading, only the alternative text. I'll keep playing with it

Comment: That sounds like that the image can't be found. Check if the URL is correct.

Comment: The backslash before 'images' was the issue, Thanks @putvande!

Comment: Check with other browsers as well. May be there is some browser issue (most likely if you are currently testing on IE).